# NuGet microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech produces 0kb files

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, nuget-package, azure-cognitive-services

I have been using this code for a month. My azure account is in good standing. However, when I run it now, it produces a 0kb file. The amount of text I am attempting to generate is around 700 words.

```
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

namespace TextToSpeech
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            await SynthsizeAudioAsync();
        }

        static async Task SynthsizeAudioAsync()
        {
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("***", "***");
            config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-ChristopherNeural";

            AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput("D:\\file.wav");
            using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, audioConfig);


            await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

There are no errors, but when it attempts to synthesize the speech it "crashes" and creates a 0kb file. I have tried generating an mp3 instead and it creats a 0kb mp3. I am not sure what to do from here. Thanks for looking into this.

I tried to change the api key, I have tried to change the voice. I have upgraded my azure account to basic plan. I have tried to add logging but it is actually running all the code. It thinks that it has finished but really the files are empty.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> However, when I run it now, it produces a 0kb file. The amount of text I am attempting to generate is around 700 words.

Based on the code you provided, the issue might be related to the audio output file path. The code is set up to output a .wav file to **`"D:\file.wav"`**, but it's possible that the file path is incorrect or the file is being overwritten or deleted by another process.

You can use the below-updated code to Synthesize the speech.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

namespace TextToSpeech
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            try
            {
                await SynthesizeAudioAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Speech synthesis completed successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesis failed: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        static async Task SynthesizeAudioAsync()
        {
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("Your speech key", "your location");
            config.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-ChristopherNeural";

            string outputFile = "C:\\Users\\file.wav";
            AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput(outputFile);
            using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, audioConfig);

            Console.WriteLine($"Synthesizing speech to {outputFile}...");
            var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Hello!");

            if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Speech synthesis completed.");
            }
            else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
            {
                var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesis cancelled: {cancellation.Reason}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesis failed: {result.Reason}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Synthesizing speech to C:\Users\file.wav...
Speech synthesis completed.
Speech synthesis completed successfully.
```

[image]

**File.wav:**
The above code was executed successfully you can see the file.wav is downloaded in my local folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out. I was using the free f0 (free) pricing tier. Although I updated my azure service to pay as you go, I was still using the free tier for the service apparently and my monthly quota was used for neural speech. I realized this when I saw blocked calls in the metrics. I really wish there was a way to see how much of the monthly quota was used...but anyway, I was able to fix this by paying basically.

Comment: It is nice you found the answer yourself. If you think that other could be of any help, some more information on what to look for would be intresting. (Also sharing wishes on what is not, does not help others so maybe remove that part of the answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).